# How to reset iBooks app in OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, mac, books

How can I reset the iBooks app, I mean completely reset it to the version that was installed and when first opened, where the app would show "Welcome to iBooks" and "Get Started"?

I think I must remove a *.plist* file or something similar from Library, right?

Comment: I do not use iBooks however the only way I could get Welcome to iBooks screen back was to delete the "$HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.iBooksX" folder. Note that in doing this is may remove access to preexisting iBooks content, I don't know for sure since I do not use iBooks.  Proceed at your own risk! (And why I'm posting this as a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: @user3439894 worked, but only once! The next time I turned it on and opened the app it was not the welcome screen! None of the ways worked. I think I should find a better way by myself ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal.app (found in the `/Applications/Utilities/` folder), run this command and arguments:

```
/usr/bin/defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iBooks
```

This will wipe the plist file, but may not trash it.

Now when you open iBooks, the settings will be back to the default.

This same command will work with other apps using the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. The app crashed once, but it's working fine now.